# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1af09f8 in tid 4357

Tags: android, android-components

And here it is the error trace....

```
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PSR1.180720.093/5456446:userdebug/dev-keys'
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4357, tid: 4357, name: sens.eliofamily  >>> fr.technosens.eliofamily <<<
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1af09f8
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     eax e500fa74  ebx 0000000c  ecx 01af09e8  edx 00000006
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     edi ffbf0a50  esi 73454648
2019-05-16 10:08:52.266 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     ebp ffbf0868  esp ffbf0868  eip eb2c2cb6
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000ffcb6  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (Bitmap_hasAlpha(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long)+22)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 003cc2f2  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ca000) (android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeIsUpToDate [DEDUPED]+162)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00419272  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.graphics.Bitmap.hasAlpha+26)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.359 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 001ef4a0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-0h2V3seT-afyydhcf64Oaw==/base.apk!classes2.dex (deleted) (android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable.getOpacity+32)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 00bb5d6a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.widget.ImageView.isOpaque+32)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 00b8789a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.View.invalidateInternal+88)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 00295229  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+985)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 005be028  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+664)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 005e3021  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15009)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 00b877c6  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.View.invalidate+34)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 00b8775e  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.view.View.invalidate+2)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 00bb6bd8  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable+56)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 0005b3a0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-0h2V3seT-afyydhcf64Oaw==/base.apk (deleted) (fr.technosens.eliofamily.pictures.BitmapManager.setRoundedDrawable+104)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 0005bd7e  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-0h2V3seT-afyydhcf64Oaw==/base.apk (deleted) (fr.technosens.eliofamily.pictures.Photo$BitmapWorkerTask.onPostExecute+150)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 0005bdcc  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-0h2V3seT-afyydhcf64Oaw==/base.apk (deleted) (fr.technosens.eliofamily.pictures.Photo$BitmapWorkerTask.onPostExecute+4)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #64 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #65 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #66 pc 005bfbf2  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+706)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #67 pc 005e6aa1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29985)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #68 pc 00c3ab68  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.AsyncTask.finish+20)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #69 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #70 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #71 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #72 pc 005bda66  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+342)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #73 pc 005e2e21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14497)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #74 pc 00c3ab48  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.AsyncTask.access$600)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #75 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #76 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #77 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #78 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #79 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #80 pc 00ad5b52  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage+50)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #81 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #82 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #83 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #84 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #85 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #86 pc 00ae396a  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+42)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #87 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #88 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #89 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #90 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #91 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #92 pc 00aeaa58  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+404)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #93 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #94 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #95 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #96 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #97 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #98 pc 00384ca2  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+214)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #99 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #100 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #101 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #102 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #103 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #104 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #105 pc 004d3349  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+89)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #106 pc 004d502e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+1422)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #107 pc 00449783  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+83)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #108 pc 0011d778  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x114000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+168)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #109 pc 005f0b82  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #110 pc 000a30ce  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #111 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #112 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #113 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #114 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #115 pc 00c0b7d2  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #116 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #117 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #118 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #119 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #120 pc 00badc3c  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ca000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3100)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #121 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #122 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #123 pc 004d3349  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+89)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #124 pc 004d2fcd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+429)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #125 pc 003a784d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+925)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.360 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #126 pc 000d9273  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2867)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.361 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #127 pc 000c6d29  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+73)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.361 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #128 pc 0007097e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+62)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.361 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #129 pc 00073e78  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+744)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.361 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #130 pc 00001bb2  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1506)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.361 4469-4469/? A/DEBUG:     #131 pc 000c0f54  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
2019-05-16 10:08:52.625 1770-1770/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
2019-05-16 10:08:52.632 1648-1648/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/4357/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-05-16 10:08:52.644 1750-1782/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-05-16 10:08:52.678 1906-2008/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '801ac31 fr.technosens.eliofamily/fr.technosens.eliofamily.sip.SelectCallOptionActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-05-16 10:08:52.679 1906-2008/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'e10ef7 fr.technosens.eliofamily/fr.technosens.eliofamily.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-05-16 10:08:52.681 1750-1962/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-05-16 10:08:52.733 2640-2680/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/s.nexuslaunche: Failed to open APK '/data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-lP6p1avdsFGlzOARLCfbQQ==/base.apk' I/O error
2019-05-16 10:08:52.733 2640-2680/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-lP6p1avdsFGlzOARLCfbQQ==/base.apk
2019-05-16 10:08:52.733 2640-2680/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/s.nexuslaunche: Failed to open APK '/data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-lP6p1avdsFGlzOARLCfbQQ==/base.apk' I/O error
2019-05-16 10:08:52.733 2640-2680/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/fr.technosens.eliofamily-lP6p1avdsFGlzOARLCfbQQ==/base.apk
```

I have this problem since I began to implement Arquitecture components: 
I am using ViewModel, LiveData, Room, RXJava, and Retrofit, but I don't know why my application crashes and I don't have any kind of error trace linking to my app, no RuntimeException, NullPointer or similar....

Thank u very much for the help!